# Physical labeling of switches and patch bays

Tags: switch, patch-panel

This has to do with the physical install of network equipment, if there is a better place to ask please let me know.

How do you physically label your switches and patch panels?  I'm having trouble finding any sort of industry best practice or standard on this.

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for a product or service.

Comment: Brother(tm) label maker. Spreadsheet detailing what's where. Toe tags.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The *ANSI/TIA-606 Administration Standard for Telecommunications Infrastructure* has a set of guidelines to promote a standard method of labeling, including:

- Classes of Administration
- Optional Identifiers for Infrastructure Elements
- Color-Coding Identification
- Permanent Labels
- Administration Systems Using Records, Linkages and Reports
- Automated Infrastructure Management Systems
- Annexes addressing Identification of Patch Cords, Equipment Cords,
  and Direct Equipment-to-Equipment Cables, Telecommunications
  Grounding System Identification Example, and Graphical, Symbology,
  Drawing Elements of Administration, and Administration of Remote
  Powering

> It establishes guidelines for owners, end users, manufacturers,
>   consultants, contractors, designers, installers, and facilities
>   administrators involved in the administration of the
>   telecommunications infrastructure.

---

Personally, I have used a small PC-connected label printer and some cable tags onto which I place labels for the cables. Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oops, good to know!